# Compilation error only in server: The base class includes the field ‘MyControl_1′, but its type (MyControl) is not compatible (ASP.MyControl_ascx)

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, webforms, asp.net-2.0

I'm desperate.

We have a little project in ASP.NET (webforms) with Framework 2.0. I've made a little maintenance over a UserControl (ASCX). I'm my development machine works perfect but when I upload the file to the server this exception is thrown:

> The base class includes the field ‘MyControl_1′, but its type
>   (MyControl) is not compatible with the type of control
>   (ASP.MyControl_ascx)

I've tried almost everything:

- http://chanmingman.wordpress.com/2011/09/07/the-base-class-includes-the-field-mycontrol_1-but-its-type-mycontrol-is-not-compatible-with-the-type-of-control-asp-mycontrol_ascx/
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919284

This is only happening in production servers. I've tried to wrap the ASCX in a namespace:

CODE:

```
namespace MyControl {
   ...
}
```

ASCX:

```
Inherits="MyControl.Control"
```

ASPX that uses the control:

```
<%@Import Namespace="MyControl" %>
<%@ Register Src="Controls/SomeControl.ascx"  TagName="SomeControl" TagPrefix="uc2" %>
<uc2:SomeControlID="Control1" runat="server" />
```

The compilation mode is not using fixed assemblies naming, and I can't change it.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem.  I found the fix - change the user control declaration.

Your production server will probably be running a web app. Web Apps expect the declarations in a user control to be of a certain format. You may have placed a user control built elsewhere in a file based project into a web app?

With Web app user controls (by default) you get a `CodeBehind="MyControl.ascx.vb"` and an Inherit of `AppName.MyControl`.

With a file based project you get `CodeFile="MyControl.ascx.vb` and an Inherit of `MyControl`.

I changed the declaration in the user control until it worked. Looks like you may need to supply a new dll to the production server after you make the changes and recompile.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure if you have a `page` that already contains any `usercontrol` will be updated to publish 
so, in this case you will publish `Usercontrol` and `Page` with precompiled `dlls` for both

Answer (score 0):

I went to the page the OP provided:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/919284?wa=wsignin1.0

The second suggestion worked for me:

> Method 2: Reorder the folders in the application

So, in the end, I put all the controls in the same subfolder, and it worked fine. It may not be an option for everyone, but it's worth trying.